# Send email from php with tcpdf attachment

Tags: php, tcpdf

I try to send an e-mail from PHP with a TCPDF attachment. When I call the script I receive an email only the attachment is not sent.

I have searched a lot on the internet, but I can not find a solution anywhere. I hope someone can help me so that I can continue.

```
<?php
require_once('lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Josiah Njuki');
$pdf->SetTitle('Quotation Request');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, '', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);


$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

$pdf->AddPage();

$html = '<span style="font-size:7pt;">' . $_SESSION['content'] . '</span>';
$html .= <<<EOD
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);


//$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
$doc = $pdf->Output('quotation.pdf', 'S');

$name = "Name goes here";
$email = "jnjuki103@gmail.com";

$to = "test@gmail.com";

$from = "John-Smith ";

$subject = "Here is your attachment";

$fileatt = $pdf->Output('quotation.pdf', 'E');

$fileatttype = "application/pdf";

$fileattname = "newname.pdf";

$headers = "From: $from";

$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');

$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));

fclose($file);

$semi_rand = md5(time());

$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
    $message .= "\n\n";


$message .= "–{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    " filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
    $data . "\n\n" .
    "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";
```

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)

Comment: Use phpmailer, not the native php `mail` function.

Comment: You can use simple mail function to send pdf attachment. no need to use tcpdf library

Comment: @ParvejAlam I want to send a dynamic PDF

Comment: @Marvin i have a code which uses pdf file to send in mail as attachment. but before that you have to generate your dynamic pdf to a folder and use that as attachment in mail after that you can delete your pdf file from the folder.

Comment: @ParvejAlam Thkns! When I try to save the file I get a error: TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file:

Comment: have you tried $pdf->Output($location.$fileName.'.pdf', 'F'); to save pdf

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97353/save-pdf-files-in-folder-using-tcpdf

Comment: @ParvejAlam Yes I tried: $pdf->Output('pdf/test.pdf', 'F');

Comment: no not like this $pdf->Output('pdf/test.pdf', 'F');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188607/discussion-between-parvej-alam-and-marvin).